# Decorador con parametros en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, decoradores

Necesito hacer la implementacion de un decorador con clases o funciones que reciba parámetros, como el siguiente ejemplo

```
@MyDec(flag='foo de fa fa')
def bar(a,b,c):
    print('En bar(...) : ',a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class MyDec(object):
    def __init__(self, flag):
        self.flag = flag

    def __call__(self, original_func):
        decorator_self = self
        def wrappee(*args, **kwargs):
            print('en decorador antes de wrapee ', decorator_self.flag)
            original_func(*args,**kwargs)
            print('en decorador despues de wrapee', decorator_self.flag)
        return wrappee

@MyDec(flag='foo de fa fa')
def bar(a,b,c):
    print('En bar(...) : ',a,b,c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar(1, "Hola", True)

#Out:
# en decorador antes de wrapee  foo de fa fa
# en bar 1 Hola True
# en decorador despues de wrapee foo de fa fa
```

Inicialmente creamos una clase `MyDec` que va a ser el decorador, y en el constructor recibe todos los argumentos que sean necesarios en este caso agregamos el algumento `flag`. En el metodo `__call__(self)` que es el que se ejecuta cuando agregamos el decorador `@MyDec(flag='foo de fa fa')` en la funcion. Dentro de los argumentos de `__call__` esta `original_func`que es la funcion a la cual se le a colocado el decorador. Y dentro de `wrappee()` recibimos los argumentos de la funcion y posteriormente ejecutamos la funcion `original_func(*args,**kwargs)` y le pasamos los argumentos y los KeyWordsArguments